# Use point symbology tools in geometry generator of a polygon

Tags: qgis, symbology, geometry-generator

In a polygon layer I have a simple geometry generator to get the centroid  `centroid($geometry)`. Using this I would like to apply a Heatmap symbology or Graduated by Size symbology but this is only possible using a native point source.

[image]

There is no option to use Method --> Graduated by size (unless we convert to points). For example, if the data is points we can do the following

[image]

**Is there a way to do this without creating a new dataset or virtual layer?** Maybe a data overide on the size column. I am not sure what the calculation would be. I guess it would be to calculate the total and then apply a formula to generate the classification.

Comment: You can try the following expression `scale_linear("phosphorus",minimum( "phosphorus"),maximum("phosphorus"),1,8)` for marker size. Check the documentation : https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#scale-linear

Comment: thanks -that worked. It doesn't show in the legend but scales the icons appropriately.

Comment: Use diagrams ;)

Comment: Never had a reason to try this before...it's really good as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Diagrams](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#diagrams-properties) tab for this. Go to `Layer Pproperties > Diagrams`, then:

1. Choose a Pie Chart
2. Add your value field to the attributes list
3. Within Size menu choose "Scaled Size" with your value field as attribute. Find a suiting maximum value and scale (e.g. by clicking "Find")
4. Already done the main part
5. Style them as you like, choose a suiting positioning or add a nice legend.

[image]